# Fetch a user defined name using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Need to fetch the element by name using jquery , for fetching the name value, it is concatenated with samp (variable). cant able to form the name element. There is some problem with concatenation please help.

```
$("input[name^='resource_" + samp + "_']")
```

Full Code:

```
var samp = $(thisVal).attr('name');  //user defined name 

$("input[name^='resource_" + samp + "_']").each(function(key,val){
    alert("calcwk entered");
    if ($(this).val() === '') {
        theVal  = 0;
    }
    else {
        theVal = parseInt($(this).val());
    }
    tot = tot + theVal;
    alert("calcwk exit");
});
```

Comment: The concatenation itself looks fine. Do you have a specific problem with the code?

Comment: Could you provide a HTML ?

Comment: but my alert(calcwk entered) is not getting called

Comment: Might `samp` contain any whitespace?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since we cannot be sure of what the format the value "samp" will contain we need to make sure that the value is properly covered with right quotes.

```
$('[property=value]');
```

works as you have no spaces or anyway that the selector doesn't instantly know where the end of the property value is, whereas

```
$('[property=my value]');
```

confuses the parser for the system and as such you need to correctly "escape" or "wrap" the value with quotes eg:

```
$('[property="my value"]');
```

here's my version of your code for help

```
var samp = $(thisVal).attr('name'),   //user defined name 
    tot = 0                           //define the total
;

$('input[name^="resource_' + samp + '_"]').each(function(key,val){
    var theVal = $(this).val(); // do a jQuery call once per item
    if (theVal === '') {
        theVal  = 0; // if this is text change to 0
    }

    tot += parseInt(theVal); // no need with else, parseInt everything
    alert("calcwk exit");
});
```

As an example, I've created this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fua9rtjd/

Answer (score 1):

Has `name` attribute the selected `thisVal` element?
Here is the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yz7t4sgz/) that works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var samp = $(thisVal).attr('name');  //user defined name 

$("input[name^=resource_"+samp+"_]").each(function(key,val){
        alert("calcwk entered");
        if( $(this).val() === '' ){
            theVal  = 0;
        }
        else{
            theVal = parseInt($(this).val());
        }
        tot = tot + theVal;
        alert("calcwk exit");
    });
```

Trouble with name like: '%name%' - don't need to use '
Right: `$("input[name^=resource_"+samp+"_]")`

Comment: Trouble with name like: '%name%' - don't need to use '

Comment: You do need to use `'` to wrap the value if it contains spaces.

Comment: same issue alert is not triggered